# Is there a newer nxt_ros stack using nxt-python 2.2.2 instead of 1.2.0? (on Raspberry Pi)

Tags: control, ros, nxt, rasbperrypi, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Raspberry Pi running ROS Groovy on a Lego NXT with a Webcam and Wifi.

Youtube: [Pictures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VD3GDK7JBK4) and [complete Visualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAgHLZvX774).

The [nxt_ros](https://stack-nxt.foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg) package is using the old nxt-python 1.2.0 and the performance of the Motors is good enough for teleop, but not for controlling. Therefore, I rewrote my controller: [linefollower](https://github.com/ipa-fmw-ms/nxt_apps/blob/master/nxt_assisted_teleop/scripts/linefollower.py) in [NXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_eXactly_C), and I am starting the .rxe Machinecode with ROS directly on the NXT.

Then I found a [MotorControl for NXT](http://www.mindstorms.rwth-aachen.de/trac/wiki/MotorControl), and that it is already included in the new [nxt-python](http://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/) 2.2.2 version.

Before rewriting, the complete nxt_ros Package from nxt-python 1.2.0 to 2.2.2, does anyone knows, if this already exists somewhere?

Or maybe someone has experience with the new nxt-pythons 2.2.2 **Motor-sync**, and ideas for a new nxt base controller?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67831/is-there-a-newer-nxt_ros-stack-using-nxt-python-2.2.2-instead-of-1.2.0?-(on-raspberry-pi)/) by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-07-22**:
I added a execute "Sensor" to nxt_ros, to Start a NXT .rxe Program configured by the robot.yaml.

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-07-24**:
Since I would like to have the same Performance of the Linefollwer.rxe for teleop, I will start porting the nxt-python 2.2.2 to nxt_ros (based on 1.2.0) to have the complete MotorControl, and also setting the I2C Bus faster on the NXT.
But don,t have time till mid of October for doing this. :-(

**Comment by [mdtobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5215/mdtobi/) on 2013-08-18**:
@msieber: I'm currently catkinizing the nxt_ros package because I need it for my master thesis. I already thought about updating it to the new nxt-python version, but hesitated. Perhaps we could work together on this topic to keep the nxt_ros package up-to-date?!

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-08-25**:
@mdtobi How far are you? can I see it somewhere? Keeping the NXT up-to-date sounds great. But, as already said, I have Exams and also regular work, so don't rely on me if it's for a Thesis. maybe we should start a SIG as IsaacSaito suggested in the other discussion

**Comment by [mdtobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5215/mdtobi/) on 2013-08-26**:
@msieber I started migrating but run into some building-errors due to a change of the rviz::display interface. Therefore I was used to understand the rviz-plugin mechanism in more detail. As soon as I have time (estimated Wednesday/Thursday), I keep on solving these issues, hoping not to receive further errors.
I'm going to upload my progress as soon as I be able to create an error-free build. (I don't like half-finished commits...)
Afterwards I will look more deeper into the nxt_python stack to understand how the nxt-python lib is used and how to replace it.

Besides, I also think we should start a SIG because I think there are a few more aspects to look at (Implement more sensors, using the new EV3, Migration to Hydro, and so on..). Therefore will create one.

About my thesis: Don't worry - my deadline is next january, so I have enought time ;-)

**Comment by [bjarkijoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8966/bjarkijoha/) on 2013-11-19**:
Hey guys, is there any progress on this? Did you start an SIG or anything?

**Comment by [mdtobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5215/mdtobi/) on 2013-11-19**:
Sorry, I forgot to mention it here:
Yes, there is a SIG (although I'm the only member). I also forked the nxt_ros stack (https://github.com/ToPitz/nxt_ros_catkin) and migrated it to the catkin build system.
But there some other building lots (winros), which is why I wasn't able to test it until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI the SIG at http://wiki.ros.org/sig/NXT and now has 2 members.

---

Originally posted by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) with karma: 81 on 2014-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0